In standard C, is the expression "i = (i = 1) + 1;" well defined?
In standard C, is the expression i = (i = 1) + 1; well defined?
What's the difference between it and i = ++i + 1; from the perspective of sequence points?
Someone told me there is a sequence point after (i=1) in i = (i = 1) + 1;, so the expression is well defined, is that right?

Whether it's well defined or not, there's certainly a clearer way to write whatever it's supposed to mean, likely i = 2;.

The expression i = (i = 1) + 1 contains undefined behavior because i is modified more than once in the expression without a sequence point (or more accurately, the modifications are unsequenced).
This rule is spelled out in section 6.5p2 of the C standard:

If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either
a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an
unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.

Each of the two assignment operators has the side effect of updating i.  Neither the parenthesis around the subexpression i = 1 nor the = operator within introduce a sequence point, so this expression violates the above clause.
For the same reason, i = ++i + 1; also contains undefined behavior.

Well, parentheses never introduce a sequence point anywhere. The point is that the assignment operator doesn't either.

That's irrelevant per 6.5.16 though: "The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is
sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands". "sequence point" is not the only way sequencing is introduced.

Summary: The i=1 side effect is not sequenced in relation to the value computation of the left-most i and so it is undefined behavior. The left-most i=... side-effect is however sequenced in relation to the side effect (i = 1) but that's irrelevant since we already have undefined behavior.

There is no sequence point in the expression save for the one at the ; in the end.
In some cases, operands may define a sequencing order regardless of sequence points, however.  The assignment operator does this (C17 6.5.16):

The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands. The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.

So the subexpression (i = 1) is well-defined in itself. There is only one side effect updating i and no value computations.
And as per above, the left-most i=... side effect is sequenced after the i = 1 side effect. This is not the problem.
However, the side affect of updating i = 1 is not sequenced in relation to the value computation of the left-most i. As noted in the quoted part, the evaluations of the operands of = are unsequenced.
C defines a value computation in 5.1.2.3:

Evaluation of an expression in general includes both value computations and initiation of side effects. Value computation for an lvalue expression includes determining the identity of the designated object.

And then 6.5 stating undefined behavior:

The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator.
If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the
same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior
is undefined.

(Scalar meaning plain variable or pointer.)
